# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[X]/(X^2+X+1)$ a Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[X]/(X^2+X+1)$ a Euclidean domain? If it is not, is it a principal ideal domain?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it can't be a domain as it contains non-zero zero divisors, since

$$x^2+x+1=(x-1)^2\pmod 3\Longrightarrow \Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle\,\,\text{is not a domain}\iff$$

$$ \langle x^2+x+1\rangle\,\,\,\text{not a prime ideal}\iff x^2+x+1\,\,\,\text{reducible}
$$

Anyway, as a homomorphic image of a principal ideal ring it is is principal.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $F$ is a field. Then $F[x]$ is a P.I.D. For the quotient $F[x]/(f(x))$ to be an integral domain, $f(x)$ needs to be a prime element in $F[x]$. But in a P.I.D, primes are same as irreducible elements. Since $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ is not irreducible in the field $\Bbb F_3$, the given quotient cannot be even an integral domain.

Comment: In any integral domain prime implies irreducible.

Comment: @JSchlather Indeed, that is correct. I guess I used a bit more than I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It isn't even reduced. Note that $x^2+x+1=(x+2)^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.

Comment: Why does that mean you can't have the Euclidean algorithm. Apologies for being slow.

Comment: @J.Lyman I think what Alex is getting at is that it's not even an integral domain since $(x+2)(x+2)=0$ in the quotient ring.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x^2+x+1$ has a root in $\Bbb F_3$.